# Is there a way to apply a loop in cql file cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have to run the following insert query 1000 times in BATCH just after loading a schema.

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.messages (messageid, message) VALUES
(uuid(), 'random');
```

My current implementation is a `radom.cql` file, which has 1000 entries like the script below. And then I use SOURCE command to apply them after my schema upload.

```
BEGIN BATCH
INSERT INTO keyspace.messages (messageid, message) VALUES (uuid(), 'random');
INSERT INTO keyspace.messages (messageid, message) VALUES (uuid(), 'random');
INSERT INTO keyspace.messages (messageid, message) VALUES (uuid(), 'random');
...till 1000 times
APPLY BATCH;
```

Is there any better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: No way to really do that.  But you should get rid of the BEGIN/APPLY BATCH statements.  What you're doing is letting Cassandra designate a single node to coordinate 1000 INSERTs to all of the remaining nodes.  That's a good way to kill a node if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Aaron. It is not good to apply batch muti-partition data entries.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra doesn't have any PL/SQL constructs or stored procedures yet, so it's impossible.

You have to do it from application side and batch doesn't help in this scenario and is a bad way of using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sreekar. I don't want to do it from application side because it is only one time activity after schema upload. you are right it is bad to use batch here. So i will remove BIGIN/APPLY batch from random.cql. Does this sound ok ?